# Compiling model file takes for ever with xcode 7.2

Tags: ios, core-data, xcode7

I have updated my Xcode to 7.2 and projects with core data could not be compiled any more.Compile stuck on "Compiling x of x data models".Any idea?
Running Xcode Version 7.2 (7C68) & OS X 10.11.2 (15C50) El Capitan

Comment: Clean your build folder (Shift-alt-⌘-K).

Comment: @Mundi I have cleaned it many times.Nothing happened.

Comment: It often helps to restart the computer as well.

Comment: same here, restarting helps but nothing else ... pretty frustrating!

Comment: Try deleting derived data. `Window / Projects`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same here, been experiencing this issue fairly frequently with the latest (7.2 7C68) Xcode build. This one is frustrating but seems a restart is the only reliable solution currently.